# Xcode versions 6 and 7 crash when trying to open .sks files

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, crash, sprite-kit

Xcode both versions 6 and 7, fails to open `.sks` files. When I doubleclick on the file, e.g. `GameScene.sks`, Xcode just crashes and closes swift project without any messages. Ok, there's only one messagebox appears:

> "Send crash report?"

which is not quite informative. I don't have any "old" libraries and crash happens for every minor and major versions from 6 to 7.

What could the issue be?

Comment: Finally, Apple fixed this in XCode 8.